# How to overwrite html code from master page(template) on child page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I Have master page with non editable area div "menu-bar" so when i change entry on master page  it will change on all child pages.

Problem is that i have class "curent" wich changes background of box "POLAZNA" but on child page i need to change it to "O NAMA" but because it is non editable area i can not.

How do I solve my problem?

```
<div id="menu-bar">

  <li class="current"><a href="index.html" class="current">POLAZNA</a></li>
  <li><a href="o-nama.html">O NAMA</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="o-nama.html">Društvo MS BPŽ</a></li>
      <li><a href="klub-ng.html">Klub Nova Gradiška</a></li>
      <li><a href="dokumenti.html">Dokumenti</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="ms.html">MS</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="lijecenje.html">Liječenje</a></li>
      <li><a href="terapija.html">Fizikalna terapija</a></li>
      <li><a href="pomagala.html">Ortopedska pomagala</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="projekti.html">PROJEKTI</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="asistenti.html">Osobni asistenti</a></li>
      <li><a href="prevencija.html">Prevencija institucionalizacije</a></li>
      <li><a href="projekt-sb.html">Projekt grada SB</a></li>
      <li><a href="radovi.html">Javni radovi</a></li>
      <li><a href="ostali-projekti.html">Ostali projekti/ programi</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="donatori.html">DONATORI</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="mspm.html">MSPM</a></li>
      <li><a href="grad-sb.html">Grad SB</a></li>
      <li><a href="grad-ng.html">Grad NG</a></li>
      <li><a href="bpz.html">BPŽ</a></li>
      <li><a href="hzz.html">HZZ</a></li>
      <li><a href="dm.html">DM</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="forum/index.php">FORUM</a></li>
  <li><a href="kontakt.html">KONTAKT</a></li>
    </div>
```

Comment: if you can't edit the code in the menu, maybe you could set a hidden ID in the page containing the selected menu ID, then use jquery to add the "current" class to the LI with that ID?

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I have to mention that I am a novice when it comes to jquery so if you can make an example of the code. It is not that im lazy but web design and programing is not my main branch.

Comment: I assume you have the jquery library in your layout and that you are able to edit the LI in the master page, just not on the individual pages, is that correct?

Comment: yes i have jquery library in my layout and yes i can edit evertything on master page but not in individual pages because I need it to be non editable area so when i ad or remove something in menu bar on master page it will update all of the child pages

Comment: ok, ideally this should not be something done with javascript, you should be setting the selected menu on the server before it hits the browser. I can make something for you but it would require you setting a value on each child page to set the "selected menu".. would that be ok?

Comment: yes that would be ok, because before I put any child page on server I must edit it first. thx for your effort I will try it tomorrow and let you know how it works

Answer (score 0):

This is a way that you can do it using jQuery:
Its important to note that I have added classes to each LI, they are in sequence so starting at `li_a` then each child of `li_a` will have a class starting with `a` so `a_1` then `a_2`. .. the next `li` would have a class of `li_b` and so on...

here is a fiddle showing the code below in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Wq6p9/

HTML:

```
<!--master layout stuff here -->
    <div id="menu-bar">
        <ul>
          <li class="li_a"><a href="#" class="a_1">POLAZNA</a></li>
          <li class="li_b"><a href="o-nama.html" class="b_1">O NAMA</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#" class="b_2">Društvo MS BPŽ</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="b_3">Klub Nova Gradiška</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="b_4">Dokumenti</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="li_c"><a href="#" class="c_1">MS</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#" class="c_2">Liječenje</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="c_3">Fizikalna terapija</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="c_4">Ortopedska pomagala</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
            <!-- etc -->
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- page here -->

    <!-- this is the hidden to set the menu -->
    <input type="hidden" id="selID" value="c_3" />
    <!-- End of page here -->
```

Script:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var selID = $('#selID').val(),
            liID = selID.split("_")[0];

        //this first row will select the outer menu when the sub menu it selected
        //comment this out if you don't want it 
        $('#menu-bar .' + liID + '_1').addClass('current');
        //this one selects the actual menu item
        $('#menu-bar .' + selID).addClass('current');

    });
```

Comment: Thx it works just fine! Im only having problem with some pages because Im having more then one script loading on start and i thing I know which one ...

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://form.jotformeu.com/jsform/33351671100340"></script>

Im trying to implement jQuery.noConflict() code, but for now Im having problems. I know that for some of you It is easy but for us who are not so good with jQuery It si a bit of a problem.

Comment: there should not be conflicts with what I have given you above, you just make sure that what I have given you is below your link to jquery, if you still have trouble let me know.

Comment: On index page your code works fine. But on other child page like my articles I have some more scripts.

<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/textsizer.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/lightbox-2.6.min.js"></script>
<link href="../css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<style type="text/css">
<!--
a:link {text-decoration: none}

}
-->
</style>

Comment: you have the jquery library twice, you only need 1 version. keep /jquery-1.10.2.min.js and remove /jquery-1.9.1.js see how you get on with that.

Comment: I have solved problem ... deleted jquery-1.10.2.min.js and left   jquery-1.9.1.js. Then i have added jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js and now every thing works. 

Thank you for your effort!

If i have anymore glitches will let you know ...

Comment: Well this is embarrassing... My fix is good on some pages but on others not. Is it possible to send you my code so you can have a look?

Comment: Sure, feel free to create a jsfiddle with your code, post a link and I'll take a look for you.

Comment: I have updated your jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Wq6p9/2/, as you can see i have script above yours, when i delete that script and external scripts jquery-1.3.2.min-tab.js and jquery-ui-1.7.custom.min-tab.js that runs my tabs on page, your code works